# Pytorch PPO implementation is not learning

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

This PPO implementation has a bug somewhere and I can't figure out what's wrong. The network returns a normal distribution and a value estimate from the critic. The last layer of the actor provides four `F.tanh`ed action values, which are used as mean value for the distribution. `nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(action_dim))` is the standard deviation.

The trajectories for 20 parallel agents are added to the same memory. Episode length is 1000 and `memory.sample()` returns a `np.random.permutation` of the 20k memory entries as tensors with batches of size 64. Before stacking the batch tensors, the values are stored as (1,-1) tensors in `collection.deque`s. The returned tensors are `detach()`ed.

environment

```
brain_name = envs.brain_names[0]
env_info = envs.reset(train_mode=True)[brain_name] 
env_info = envs.step(actions.cpu().detach().numpy())[brain_name]
next_states = env_info.vector_observations
rewards = env_info.rewards                 
dones = env_info.local_done
```

update step

```
def clipped_surrogate_update(policy, memory, num_epochs=10, clip_param=0.2, gradient_clip=5, beta=0.001, value_loss_coeff=0.5):

    advantages_batch, states_batch, log_probs_old_batch, returns_batch, actions_batch = memory.sample()

    advantages_batch = (advantages_batch - advantages_batch.mean()) / advantages_batch.std()

    for _ in range(num_epochs):
        for i in range(len(advantages_batch)):

            advantages_sample = advantages_batch[i]
            states_sample = states_batch[i]
            log_probs_old_sample = log_probs_old_batch[i]
            returns_sample = returns_batch[i]
            actions_sample = actions_batch[i]

            dist, values = policy(states_sample)

            log_probs_new = dist.log_prob(actions_sample.to(device)).sum(-1).unsqueeze(-1)
            entropy = dist.entropy().sum(-1).unsqueeze(-1).mean()

            ratio = (log_probs_new - log_probs_old_sample).exp()

            clipped_ratio = torch.clamp(ratio, 1-clip_param, 1+clip_param)
            clipped_surrogate_loss = -torch.min(ratio*advantages_sample, clipped_ratio*advantages_sample).mean()
            value_function_loss = (returns_sample - values).pow(2).mean()

            Loss = clipped_surrogate_loss - beta * entropy + value_loss_coeff * value_function_loss

            optimizer_policy.zero_grad()
            Loss.backward()
            torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(policy.parameters(), gradient_clip)
            optimizer_policy.step()
            del Loss
```

data sampling

```
def collect_trajectories(envs, env_info, policy, memory, tmax=200, nrand=0, gae_tau = 0.95, discount = 0.995):

    next_episode = False   

    states = env_info.vector_observations
    n_agents = len(env_info.agents)

    state_list=[]
    reward_list=[]
    prob_list=[]
    action_list=[]  
    value_list=[]

    if nrand > 0:
        # perform nrand random steps
        for _ in range(nrand):
            actions = np.random.randn(num_agents, action_size) 
            actions = np.clip(actions, -1, 1)             
            env_info = envs.step(actions)[brain_name]           
            states = env_info.vector_observations        


    for t in range(tmax):   

        states = torch.FloatTensor(states).to(device)
        dist, values = policy(states)

        actions = dist.sample()
        probs = dist.log_prob(actions).sum(-1).unsqueeze(-1) 

        env_info = envs.step(actions.cpu().detach().numpy())[brain_name] 
        next_states = env_info.vector_observations
        rewards = env_info.rewards                                          
        dones = env_info.local_done           

        state_list.append(states)
        reward_list.append(rewards)
        prob_list.append(probs)
        action_list.append(actions)
        value_list.append(values)

        states = next_states


        if np.any(dones):
            next_episode = True
            break


    _, next_value = policy(torch.FloatTensor(states).to(device))

    reward_arr = np.array(reward_list)
    undiscounted_rewards = np.sum(reward_arr, axis=0)

    state_arr = torch.stack(state_list)
    prob_arr = torch.stack(prob_list)
    action_arr = torch.stack(action_list)
    value_arr = torch.stack(value_list)

    reward_arr = torch.FloatTensor(reward_arr[:, :, np.newaxis])

    advantage_list = []
    return_list = []

    returns = next_value.detach()
    advantages = torch.FloatTensor(np.zeros((n_agents, 1)))
    for i in reversed(range(state_arr.shape[0])):

        returns = reward_arr[i] + discount * returns

        td_error = reward_arr[i] + discount * next_value - value_arr[i]
        advantages = advantages * gae_tau * discount + td_error
        next_value = value_arr[i]           

        advantage_list.append(advantages.detach())
        return_list.append(returns.detach())


    advantage_arr = torch.stack(advantage_list) 
    return_arr = torch.stack(return_list)

    for i in range(state_arr.shape[0]):
        memory.add({'advantages': advantage_arr[i],
                    'states': state_arr[i],
                    'log_probs_old': prob_arr[i],
                    'returns': return_arr[i],
                    'actions': action_arr[i]})

    return undiscounted_rewards, next_episode
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Generalized Advantage Estimation loop `advantages` and `returns` are added in reversed order.

```
advantage_list.insert(0, advantages.detach())
return_list.insert(0, returns.detach())
```